# UINavigationItem BackButtonItem not displaying

Tags: ios4, uibutton, uinavigationitem

Using the below code I am implementing my own Navigation Bar.  For some reason when I run my app nothing is showing up for a back (left-arrow) button on the navigation bar.  However if I change the code to leftBarButtonItem, the button does appear.

```
// Draw Navigation Bar
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[navigationBar setDelegate:self];

UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                               target:nil 
                                                               action:nil];
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
[navigationBar release];
[backButton release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
// Draw Navigation Bar
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[navigationBar setDelegate:self];

UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
// add selector
[button setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
[navigationBar release];
[backButton release];
```

Answer (score 3):

The `backBarButtonItem` is set by the parent ViewController.
In other words, it's not set by the `ViewController` on which you see it but by the `ViewController` to which it points. So if your `ViewController` is the first in line, it just won't have a back button.

Also, you are creating a NavigtionBar by yourself. This is usually not the way to go, a `UINavigationBar` isn't a UI-Element like a Button or a Label. You should rather use a `UINavigationController` to handle all the pushing and popping of your `ViewControllers`.

Comment: I understand that, and normally I would implement the navigation bar like you have said.  However, in this case I have programmatically created a SplitView which means that my SplitViewController is the UINavigationController.  What I want to do is hide the SplitView's NavigationBar and build unique NavigationBar's for my left and right  ViewControllers